# What’s the cheapest hardware that include a 8GB NVIDIA GPU?

Tags: graphics-cards, mini-pc

I’m building a product that uses NVIDIA GPUs and need 8GB of GPU RAM. 
also, my code is currently based on Windows. 
Is there a box with an Intel processor that can run any kind of Windows (embedded?) and have the requested GPU?

Eventually I’ll need hundreds or thousands of devices and my target is $600-700 per device. 
The preference is to find an off the shelf product. 
Is this possible or nothing like that in the market?

Comment: That's a lot of VRAM; why do you need so much?